# How can I detect what alphabet is being used in utf8?

Tags: c, unicode, utf-8

I want a quick and dirty way of determining what language the user is writing in. I know that there is a Google API which will detect the difference between French and Spanish (even though they both use mostly the same alphabet), but I don't want the latency. Essentially, I know that the Latin alphabet has a lot of confusion as to what language it is using. Other alphabets, however, don't. For example, if there is a character using hiragana (part of the Japanese writing system) there is no confusion as to the language. Therefore, I don't need to ask Google.

Therefore, I would like to be able to do something simple like say that `שלום` uses the Hebrew alphabet and `こんにちは` uses Japanese characters. How do I get that alphabet string?

"Bonjour", "Hello", etc. should return "Latin" or "English" (Then I'll ask Google for the real language). "こんにちは" should return "Hiragana" or "Japanese". "שלום" should return "Hebrew".

Comment: You do realize that you can't reliably detect languages based on just the set of characters they use, right? What kind of accuracy are you looking for here?

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding, not an alphabet. You probably mean a Unicode codepoint alphabet?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen "quick and dirty". I noted the fact that you mention when I talked about french and spanish.

Comment: @chacham15: Yes, but the second question, "what kind of accuracy are you looking for?" still holds. Accuracy can range anywhere from detecting every language in the world flawlessly to saying "Japanese or not Japanese".

Comment: Are you asking for just a codepoint to script name function?

Comment: Each character belongs to one "code range", which you can simply look up in the  Unicode database. Obviously the question only makes sense for "writing systems" and not for "languages", oui?

Comment: @Kerrek: Which is fine, if you're okay with dozens of languages being called "Basic Latin".

Comment: @fge yes, i know that utf8 is an encoding. I dont know more precise terminology. So I will try to clarify in the question a bit more.

Comment: I guess the real question is, "what do you need this for?"

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I want a quick and dirty way of categorizing text by language

Comment: @chacham15: Unfortunately that still doesn't answer the question, "what kind of accuracy do you need?". Try to state your question a bit better. The most "quick and dirty" and naive implementation is likely to be so inaccurate it's useless in practice (i.e. it could group half the languages in the world into one)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Kerrek SB's suggestion is like what i was looking for

Comment: +1 @MattiVirkkunen. Or as I like to say to my Italian, German, French, Spanish, Romanian, etc. friends:  You should be able to understand this exquisite sentence, since it's in the Roman alphabet.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I updated the question to explain my reasoning a bit better

Comment: "For example, if there is a character using hiragana [..] there is no confusion as to the language." Is it really? What if the text is in English, but about something from Japan and quoting something in Hiragana?

Comment: Well, the detector would be correct in noting that the letters in hiragana are indeed japanese. In fact, this function is what would let me know that there is a japanese quote in some other language (because of the multiple alphabets). This would actually be better than trying to ship the data off to google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an N-gram model and then give a sufficiently large set of training data. A full example describing this technique is to be found at this page, among others:

http://phpir.com/language-detection-with-n-grams/

Although the article assumes you are implementing in PHP and by "language" you mean something like English, Italian, etc... the description may be implemented in C if you require this, and instead of using "language" as in English, etc. for the training, just use your notion of "alphabet" for the training. For example, look at all of your "Latin alphabet" strings together and consider their n-grams for n=2:

Bonjour: "Bo", "on", "nj", "jo", "ou", "ur"

Hello: "He", "el", "ll", "lo"

With enough training data, you will discover dominant combinations that are likely for all Latin text, for example, perhaps "Bo" and "el" are quite probable for text written in the "Latin alphabet". Likewise, these combinations are probably quite rare in text that is written in the "Hiragana alphabet". Similar discoveries will be made with any other alphabet classification for which you can provide sufficient training data.

This technique is also known as a Hidden Markov model or a Markov chain; searching for these keywords will give more ideas for implementation. For "quick and dirty" I would use n=2 and gather just enough training data such that the least common letter from each alphabet is encountered at least once... e.g. at least one 'z' and at least one 'ぅ' *little hiragana u.

EDIT:

For a simpler solution than N-Grams, use only basic statistical tests -- min, max and average -- to compare your Input (a string given by the user) with an Alphabet (a string of all characters in one of the alphabets you are interested).

Step 1. Place all the numerical values of the Alphabet (e.g. utf8 codes) in an array. For example, if the Alphabet to be tested against is "Basic Latin", make an array DEF := {32, 33, 34, ..., 122}.

Step 2. Place all the numerical values of the Input into an array, for example, make an array INP := {73, 102, 32, ...}.

Step 3. Calculate a score for the input based on INP and DEF. If INP really comes from the same alphabet as DEF, then I would expect the following statements to be true:

- min(INP) >= min(DEF)
- max(INP) <= max(DEF)
- avg(INP) - avg(DEF) < EPS, where EPS is a suitable constant

If all statements are true, the score should be close to 1.0. If all are false, the score should close to 0.0. After this "Score" routine is defined, all that's left is to repeat it on each alphabet you are interested in and choose the one whiich gives the highest score for a given Input.

Comment: This is an excellent "where to go after the quick and dirty hack."

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest looking at the [Unicode "Script" property](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr24/).  The latest database can be found [here](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Scripts.txt).

For a quick and dirty implementation, I'd try scanning all of the characters in the target text and looking up the script name for each one.  Pick whichever script has the most characters.